# How can I link to an .mp4 video in my site?

Tags: html, video, mp4, video-player

I have a web site and I want to link a button to a video. So whenever someone clicks the "video" buttons let's say, I want to open the `video.mp4` in a new browser. What I do is:

```
<a href="videos/engine/swf/player.swf?url=../../data/video.mp4&volume=100" target="_blank"><div>...</div></a>
```

The video is quite big (190MB) so the code above is not working. I start listening to the sound but cannot see the image.

Does anyone know how to do it? Or any simple way to just open this video as a link?

Comment: create the swf using flash or something

Comment: mm how can I do this? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: you should have a look at html5 audio and video features. html5 supports mp4, ogg, webm video file formats to display on web pages but unfortunately html5 is not supported in older browsers :(

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was thinking about html5 but I want to be able to see the video in IE7 and I think is not possible.

Comment: @Sushanta Patel — HTML 5 supports "video", the particular codecs and container formats are left to browser discretion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HTML5 tag  don't forget that MP4 is only supported by IE 9+, Chrome 5+ and Safari 3+. You should at least convert your file to WebM or Ogg to make it compatible with all recent browsers.
To do so you would need a new page (where the link goes) and in this page have this code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  /* instead of the last line you could also add the flash player*/
</video>
```

The browser will automatically select the first known format and play it. (source: [w3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp))

Hope this helps!

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C and often provide incorrect, out-of-date and sometimes conflicting data re: web standards. [Don't trust them](http://j.mp/pdGV9R).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfect in safari not in other browsers. (I had only the mp4 format). I will now convert to ogg and webm and see if it will work. But are these compatible also with IE7?

Comment: @amphetamachine: I'm not saying that they're always correct, I'm just quoting my source because I've used this code already and that it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @novellino: I'm not sure it works with IE7, unfortunately I haven't managed to find a working IE7 edition yet. But I'm guessing that it should as IE7 won't understand the <video> tag it should go on till the flash file…

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I will try this and see if i can do somethinf different for older browsers.