# Embed mp4 video in site

Tags: object, video, embed, mp4

What is the best way to embed a mp4 video in a webpage? I tried quicktime but if the user doesn't have it it takes a really long time. YouTube is not an option at this point. Any other solutions?

Edit: is there any way to use a flash player without being a swf.

(I dont really know much about video embedding, but a tried googling a lot)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I link to an .mp4 video in my site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172386/how-can-i-link-to-an-mp4-video-in-my-site)

Comment: nope didnt see that one, i will have a look